# Wordpress Admin Can't Log In

Tags: php, wordpress, url, admin, cpanel

I was attempting to move my Wordpress site from a subdirectory to the root, and went into General>Settings in the admin panel to remove the subdirectory from the URL. I left the / after the site URL, and now I can't login to the admin panel (it just redirects back to the login screen). It is not referencing the installed theme, either, but my custom styles are intact.
I have access to the code in CPanel. Is there a way to get back into the admin panel so I can correct that? Or a way to change it back via File Manager?
Thanks so much for any help!!

**EDIT** I can get to the login screen from /wp-login, but /wp-admin is throwing a 404.

Comment: You should log into phpmyadmin and adjust it in the database. table wp_options

Comment: THIS WORKED PERFECTLY!!! Thanks so much!

Comment: Glad to be of help.